# iOS - Retrieve EXIF UserComment from UIImage

Tags: ios, jpeg, exif

I have some important metadata information in the UserComment field of the EXIF header of a JPEG image. I am attempting to retrieve it with

```
NSData* jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 1.0);

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpgData, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

NSDictionary *img_metadata = [metadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

NSString* user_comment = [img_metadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

However, the img_metadata dictionary I get back no longer contains the user comment, even though it does still have other fields such as the color space and image dimensions? Is there any way to get the user comment from a UIImage object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIImage` represents a decoded image, and discards metadata. Re-encoded data (UIImageJPEGRepresentation in your case) will still contain info such as colorspace, image size and orientation since these may needed during encode/decode operations.

The only way to get the metadata is to use the original image data, can't get it from an `UIImage`.